# If I do dfm_replace() to replace words with lemmas, and want to search with KWIC, how can I map back the lemma to the original word?

Tags: r, quanteda

if I have the following data.frame:

```
df <- data.frame(text = c("Ow now brown cow","Unique New York",
                         "The sassy salesmans agonized about a bigger sale"),
                person = c("Jim", "John", "Jim"),
                year = c(1994, 1995, 1996),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
x <- corpus(df)

xdfm <- tokens(x) %>% 
    tokens_remove(stopwords("english"), padding = TRUE) %>%
    dfm(remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_punct = TRUE,
        ngrams = 1:3, remove_symbols = TRUE, concatenator= " ")

xdfmr <- dfm_replace(x, pattern = lemmaFile$V2, replacement = lemmaFile$V1)
```

`lemmaFile` is just a list to lemmatize the words. in the format of a data.frame with 2 columns.

When I peform a `kwic` like

```
 kwic(dfmr, "agonized", window = 100)
```

agonized won't show up because the lemma file would replace it with agonize. How can ensure that I'm getting the pre-lemma word in kwic and show the original text?

Comment: Check your code. `dfm_replace()` returns a DFM, but `kwic()` only works with tokens or corpus objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you cannot, at least not in the way you are approaching it.

`dfm_replace()` returns a dfm, and you cannot input a dfm into `kwic()`.  Furthermore, once you have formed ngrams, your tokens are compound tokens and will not have lemmas in the same way.

There is another way, however: work on tokens rather than on the dfm.  If you supply the unlemmatized tokens as the pattern argument for the `kwic()` match, then you can return their context in the way you want, but then supply the lemmatised tokens to dfm for further processing.  This approaches uses `tokens_replace()` rather than `dfm_replace()`.

```
xtoks <- 
    tokens(x, remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_punct = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE) %>% 
    tokens_remove(stopwords("english"), padding = TRUE)

lemmaFile = list(V2 = "agonized", V1 = "agonize")
xtoklemma <- tokens_replace(xtoks, pattern = lemmaFile$V2, replacement = lemmaFile$V1)

kwic(xtoks, lemmaFile$V2)
## [text3, 4]  sassy salesmans | agonized |  bigger sale
```

Here, the match is using the pre-lemma tokens, but you can use `xtoklemma` for further processing (constructing a dfm for instance, with or without ngrams).